# ACF Image in Reapeter inside Group doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

```
<div class="section2">
<?php
    // Stop if there's nothing to display.
    if (!have_rows('section2')) {
        return false;
    }
    if (have_rows('section2')): 
?>
        <?php while (have_rows('section2')): the_row();
    // Services Sub Repeater.
    if (have_rows('packages')): ?>
    <?php
        while (have_rows('packages')): the_row();
            $title = get_sub_field('title');
            $quote = get_sub_field('quote');
            $image = get_sub_field('image');
            $title_image = get_sub_field('title_image');
            $caption = get_sub_field('caption');
            $desc = get_sub_field('desc');
            $link_text = get_sub_field('link_text');
            $link = get_sub_field('link_text');
        ?>
            <div class="container">
                <h1><?php echo esc_html($title); ?></h1>
                <div class="quote-triangle">
                    <p>
                    <?php echo esc_html($quote); ?>
                    </p>
                    <div class="quote__moving-border"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper-content">
                    <div data-aos="fade-right">
                        <div class="wrapper-content__leftside">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="" class="left-side__icon">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="200">
                        <div class="wrapper-content__rightside">
                            <h6><?php echo esc_html($title_image); ?></h6>
                            <div class="caption"><?php echo esc_html($caption); ?></div>
                            <div class="desc">
                            <?php echo esc_html($desc); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="click">
                                <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="click__a">
                                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/img/icons/right-arrow-grey.svg" alt=""
                                        class="click__right-arrow">
                                    <h6><?php echo esc_html($link_text); ?></h6>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

This code is **Reapeter inside Group** I got this from that link https://allisontarr.com/2017/12/01/acf-repeater-within-group/ all the variables are working correctly **except the $image** I tried so hard to change the code PHP inside the  tag but nothing happened.
By the way, I'm new on Wordpress I hope to can find the solution
thanks.

Comment: After `$image` is defined, can you `print_r($image)` - what does it show? In the ACF field for the image you might need to select the radio button that says to return an image array. Maybe you're just returning the image URL.

Comment: image field either returns array, URL or ID - check that yours is returning the array

Comment: yes that's right it's just returning the URL link (http://rida.local/crunchify/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/section3-img1.png
) and what did you mean to select the radio button I'm not good at PHP as well.

Comment: I should change the configuration on the ACF and put the image to Array, not URL?

Comment: @Rida You're already outputting the image field as an array with the use of `['url']`, so just check to ensure it's actually selected to be an array and not a standard URL from within your field group; alternatively, just remove `['url']`.